# Difference between right shift bitwise and divide by two (size_t)

Tags: c

This is the binary search algorithm taken from Linux kernel 3.12.1. Because `size_t` is always `>=0`, I wonder why don't we replace `/2` by `>>` ?

```
/**
 * @key: pointer to item being searched for
 * @base: pointer to first element to search
 * @num: number of elements
 * @size: size of each element
 * @cmp: pointer to comparison function
 */
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t num, size_t size,
        int (*cmp)(const void *key, const void *elt))
{
    size_t start = 0, end = num;
    int result;

    while (start < end)
    {
        size_t mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        result = cmp(key, base + mid * size);
        if (result < 0)
            end = mid;
        else if (result > 0)
            start = mid + 1;
        else
            return (void *) base + mid * size;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why should we replace it? Is there any benefit for humans or computers?

Comment: I guess any decent compiler will optimize this expression into its most efficient form.

Comment: Why shouldn't we rewrite the kernel in pure machine code? Surely we could do much better than any stupid compiler.

Comment: @KerrekSB The suggested change is not to use machine code, but to use `>> 1` instead of `/ 2`. The two idioms should be equivalent to any C programmer, so the question is not one of writing machine code instead of C, and it is not of writing obscure C instead of clear C. I would argue that C's `/`, with its round-towards-zero behavior that make it different from Euclidean division, is the obscure operation. Not that a C programmer shouldn't know its meaning and be able to interpret it when ey sees it.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's premature optimization - and most likely the compiler is smart enough to realize and will change the division by two into a single right shift.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to give the compiler information that it does not have. The compiler already knows that `size_t` is an unsigned type, so it can compile `/ 2` as if it was `>> 1` already. Any modern compiler does this transformation.

Sometimes, the programmer has information that the compiler does not have. It can be like this:

```
/* requires y to be larger than x */
int f(int x, int y) {
  int z = y - x;
  return z / 2;
}
```

In the above function, the compiler cannot transform the division into a simple shift (although it can transform it into a longer sequence that uses a shift and avoids the division). In this case, you may consider writing `>> 1` instead of `/ 2`. But when the information can trivially be inferred from the program, let the compiler infer it. If you notice, while reading the generated assembly (which you should have been doing: it would have saved you the bother of asking this question), that sub-optimal code is generated considering the information that is easily available, file an improvement request with the developers of your compiler instead of making your source code less readable.